# Disabled driver installations through GP then removed a device

Tags: windows-10, command-line, group-policy

I have one laptop with faulty keyboard (stuck keys which occasionally write stuff on their own) and I Googled "how to turn keyboard off" ... found a way which includes Enabling ‘Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings’ in Local Group policy AND then disabling the keyboard in Device manager...

But what happened is opposite of expected, because touch-pad stopped working as well along with keyboard (after uninstalling it through Device Manager) and now Windows won't install USB keyboard or new USB mouse...

So basically... it enters Windows and integrated touchpad doesn't work, and USB keyboard and mouse go dark. All because of the policy.

Keyboard and mouse work in Troubleshoot > Command prompt... is there a way to revert that group policy to "not configured" .... or I need to reinstall everything again...

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I find an answer after posting a question. But here it is just in case someone else can't enter a Group Policy editor anymore...

> RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers" && RD /S /Q
> "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy"

Just replace %WinDir% with your real drive letter because %WinDir% won't work from Troubleshoot > Command Prompt. This basically reverts all settings in Group Policy to defaults.